# Can't connect to local MySQL instance when ran as service

Tags: windows, mysql, services

I've been running a local MySQL server for development purposes lately and for some reason never got around to running it as a service so I was constantly starting it up using the mysqld.exe every time I started doing any database work.

I've finally decided that this should be running as a service because I'm using it pretty much every day now. I easily set it up as a service and everything appeared to be working but as soon as I tried to connect to it (via Workbench) I was unexpectedly presented with a password prompt.

I've just been using the default "root" user without a password because I have no security concerns about the database or access to my box previously but now I can't access my MySQL instance using those credentials.

Stopping the service and running the mysqld.exe allows me to connect just fine with my previous credentials. What am I doing wrong here? Is the MySQL service not just running mysqld.exe on start up?

I'm running Windows 7 on this box if it makes any difference.

Comment: Did you checked you PC for services from any other mysql server installation?. Also check the path of mysqld.exe in mysql service property

Comment: The MySQL install was on to a fresh install of Windows and I've not got any other MySQL installs anywhere else on this box. The executable path is `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56` which is exactly how I've been starting MySQL manually.

Answer (score 0):

found a help document on starting MySQL as service

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html

hope this clarifies your problem.